# How to index a View from joins and subsequent queries from the view?

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing, view, sql-view

I am new to sql indexing and want to index this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    remoteId TEXT,
    text TEXT,
    timestamp INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    channelId TEXT NOT NULL,
    accountId TEXT NOT NULL,

    username TEXT NOT NULL,
    editUsername TEXT,
    wm_createdUsername TEXT,
    wm_organizedUsername TEXT,
    rc_username TEXT,
    p_messageRemoteId TEXT,
    c_messageRemoteId TEXT,
    ....

    UNIQUE (remoteId, accountId),
    FOREIGN KEY (channelId, accountId) REFERENCES channel(id, accountId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (p_messageRemoteId, accountId) REFERENCES message(remoteId, accountId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (c_messageRemoteId, accountId) REFERENCES message(remoteId, accountId) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE VIEW messageAndUser AS
SELECT ...
FROM message
LEFT JOIN user AS u ON message.username = u.name AND message.accountId = u.accountId
LEFT JOIN user AS e ON message.editUsername = e.name AND message.accountId = e.accountId
LEFT JOIN user AS wm ON message.wm_organizedUsername = wm.name AND message.accountId = wm.accountId
LEFT JOIN user AS rc ON message.rc_username = rc.name AND message.accountId = rc.accountId
LEFT JOIN user AS i ON message.i_username = i.name AND message.accountId = i.accountId;
```

channelMessages:

```
SELECT *
FROM messageAndUser
WHERE channelId=? AND accountId=?
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

;

My intuition tells me that index needs to be placed on all the parts of the AND statements as a unit.

However what Im not sure how to do is if I have a index which cover all the parts of the joins in the view, now if a query from that view, i.e. `select from view where foo=?`, do I need to create new index containg all the columns from the index for the view + foo? Or is there a way to compose this?

Comment: As a first guess, an index on `user(accountId, name)` would be very useful in those joins. Leaning how to read [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output will help a lot for identifying possible indexes, and the sqlite3 shell's `.expert` command is quite handy (Enter that, then the next query run will give index suggestions).

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/ is also really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A view can't be indexed  directly but can benefit by the indexes  present on the tables involved in the view query.

Looking to your schema and view seems you missed  the main index for join

```
table  message  column   accountId
```

do the fact that the unique index    UNIQUE (remoteId, accountId present the accountId  on the right side  .. this is not useful for the join used  in view  ..

Comment: uhm sorry I dont follow. Are you saying I should create index beginning with accoungId?

Comment: if your remoteId is less significant  then accountId  .. yes ..  if you need the index remoteId,accountId for others reason  the you should add  a new index  for accountId only (at least)

Comment: what about the multiple user joins?

Comment: the table is alway the same and for each  table alias is evaluated  the related  index.. in this case  the index  is the same but should be applied to the several diffente table alias ..  (you could try with a small view and eval the expalin plan for this)

Comment: This is another aspect   (for this you should provide the proper index  for each of the column ) the main aspect was the presence of an not optimal index  involved  in each join  ..  Once solved this the problem is simply related to (a repeated) single join  .. and for this you should think at a proper set on indexes  (if you want fast performance for the view result availability )

Comment: so youre saying I need 2 indices? Not a single big compound one?

Comment: depend  on the level optimization you want reach  ..  if you want the most fast you need  several composite index   (name, accountid)  .. ( editusername, accountid)  .. and so on ..  but  a query otimizing is a balance between  cardinality of each key, number of indexes,  db space,  time for insert rows ..  .. the column with an high cardinality should be  involved in index  but making sure that you find different column names on the left...and this is just the begin for a good queries  optimizing. I think I give you enough suggestion to be able to do a lot of tests and to evaluate the result